# CakePHP 2.0 - Cake was unable to write to File cache

Tags: file, caching, cakephp, fopen

I'm using CakePHP 2.0 RC-1. After checking out the project from SVN, the application is starting to complain that it can't write cache files to the tmp/cache directory. Since this is local, I know the directory is writeable and I can CLEARLY see that the directories are even filled with files, so the error is a bit strange.

Here are some of the errors I've encountered:

```
_cake_core_ cache was unable to write 'cake_dev_nb' to File cache

fopen(c:\cake\app\tmp\cache\models\cake_model_default_media) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: No error [CORE\Cake\Cache\Engine\FileEngine.php, line 127]
```

No error?! Wth?

Now, if I look in the FileEngine file, at line 127 it reads:

```
if (!$handle = fopen($this->_File->getPathName(), 'c')) {
            return false;
}
```

By replacing the "c" with "w", no error is encountered and everything works as it should. But, it should not be necessary to modify the core Cake libraries to work around this problem. Let me repeat that on my other computer this works as intended, without editing the core library. Both use the Windows OS and the read/write rights to the tmp/cache-folder is exactly the same.

Edit: Here's a site that experiences the error outputs I'm having locally

Example site found by Googling. Not my site: http://www.12h30.net/credit/

Any suggestions?

**Update: Here is why:** This is caused if you have a PHP-version that's too low, before 5.2.6, as outlined by "api55" in the comments. Thanks for the reply. Hope this helps you too.

Comment: what version of php do you have? remember that 2.0 still in RC stage, so it may have this kind of errors... for mode c or c+ you NEED to have php 5.2.6 or later if you don't it won't recognize that mode

Answer (score 25):

Well, in my case, when I checked my app, it hadn't the `/tmp` folder. Then I created the structure (`/tmp/cache/models`, `/tmp/cache/persistent`) and all worked well. This happened to me maybe git ignore empty folders, so they weren't created.

Comment: Indeed, version control systems often ignore empty folders.

Answer (score 17):

I had a similar problem, it was because I had chown -R www to the app/tmp directory to get Cake to run "properly" without giving everyone write privileges.  Looks like during development the only way to use the console and the web is to give everyone write privileges, or add yourself to the www group perhaps.

Easy solution:

> chmod -R 777 app/tmp

or

> chown -R username app/tmp

while using the console and

> chown -R www app/tmp

when using the web

Comment: chmod 777 is never the answer to anything, this is completely wrong and insecure !

Answer (score 3):

Just give the right `CHMOD` (`776` works fine for me) to `app/tmp`

Answer (score 0):

for windows users with the same error/warning: make sure you run the command prompt in elevated mode ;)